# How to set two tax class on single product in magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

i need to set tax rate for two tax class for "Virginia".

1. 4.0% State Sales Tax + 1.0% State Sales Tax = 5%
2. 1.0% County Sales Tax = 1%

I set tax rule like my below image:

[image: Tax rule image]

It displays in Front end like:

[image: Front end]

How can I display both tax and calculate both tax in cart page?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to assign only one Product Tax Class to one product. However you can create three Product Tax Classes for example

1) Only State Sales Tax

2) Only County Sales Tax

3) State Sales Tax and County Sales Tax

and then create two Tax Rules

*Rule1
**Product Tax Class**: Only State Sales Tax, State Sales Tax and County Sales Tax
**Tax Rate**: State Sales Tax*

*Rule2
**Product Tax Class**: Only County Sales Tax, State Sales Tax and County Sales Tax
**Tax Rate**: County Sales Tax*

Then you can be able to manage the tax rates for the products for all combinations by assigning the correct Product Tax Class. The products with class State Sales Tax and County Sales Tax will be displayed with both tax rates in cart, checkout etc.